# How to set Bottom navigation clickable in android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

How to create bottom navigation with help of navigation resource and menu in android studio.

I was trying to create bottom navigations  but I click another bottom navigations option its not working.

please help me and suggest me what I done wrong

[app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOtco.png)

***MainActivity.java:***

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private NavController navController;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.frame_layout);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);
    }
}
```

***main_activity.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"

        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="selected"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***mobile_navigation.xml:***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/galleryFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/aboutFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mycollege.ui.about.aboutFragment"
        android:label="about"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/galleryFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mycollege.ui.gallery.galleryFragment"
        android:label="gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mycollege.ui.home.homeFragment"
        android:label="home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/noticeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mycollege.ui.notice.noticeFragment"
        android:label="notice"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_notice" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/facultyFragment"
        android:name="com.example.mycollege.ui.faculty.facultyFragment"
        android:label="faculty"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_faculty" />

</navigation>
```

***menu.xml:***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:title="Home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notice_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/noticeboard"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:title="Notice" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/faculty_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/team"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:title="Faculty" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/gallery_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/gallery"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:title="Gallery" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about_navigation"
        android:icon="@drawable/writing"
        android:iconTint="@color/white"
        android:title="About" />
</menu>
```

Comment: check out this article
https://medium.com/@ChiragR10/bottomnavigationview-with-drawerlayout-using-navigation-jetpack-component-a240c9ff9133?sk=67f07a9e4e896022e100ef4af22a9865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your menu items id are the same as fragments ids.
For instance, your fragment id is `aboutFragment`, then your menu item's id should be `aboutFragment`.